# How detect and avoid multi-threading conflict in a loop with OpenMP compilation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am using an open-source simulation software that can be compiled with OpenMP-enabled cmake option. (https://github.com/oofem/oofem/)

In my class I am calling the following method in a for loop:

```
MaterialStatus *
Material :: giveStatus(GaussPoint *gp) const
/*
 * returns material status in gp corresponding to specific material class
 */
{
    MaterialStatus *status = static_cast< MaterialStatus * >( gp->giveMaterialStatus() );
    if ( status == nullptr ) {
        // create a new one
        status = this->CreateStatus(gp);

        // if newly created status is null
        // dont include it. specific instance
        // does not have status.
        if ( status ) {
            gp->setMaterialStatus( status );
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

(here is the link of code above in [Github repository](https://github.com/oofem/oofem/blob/1b70c9495cacdc40aa18788888003954094a493f/src/oofemlib/material.C#L199-L219).)

As you can see in the giveStatus method if there is no **status** already assigned, it will create and assign one, but if you call `gp->setMaterialStatus(gp)` and already there is a **status** instance assigned to **gp** the code will stop with an error.

Now my problem is if I don't compile the code with OpenMP the code will work fine, but if I use OpenMP-enabled compilation the code will stop with the error that the status is already assigned.

I am not sure what is happening, I think two objects try to get status from the same **gp** and since no **status** is assigned, the threads cannot obtain the ***status** pointer, and all of them try to set the status multiple times.

How can I obtain more information on this problem while debugging and how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`giveStatus` is clearly **not thread-safe**. Thus, calling it from multiple threads in parallel cause a **race-condition**. Indeed, some threads can concurrently check if `status` is `null` and can enter the conditional in parallel. Then `status` is set by multiple thread causing an **undefined behavior** (typically an outcome that is dependent of the order of the execution of the threads). Because this code is not designed to be thread-safe, the simplest option is to put **critical sections** so to protect the code (ie. one thread will execute the section at a time and so the functions). This can be done using the directive `#pragma omp critical`. If you want the execution to be deterministic, it is probably better to use a `#pragma omp master` so to force the same unique thread to execute a code and then share its result to others using *synchronizations* (eg. barrier, atomic, critical sections, etc.).

Alternatively you can rewrite the code so to be thread-safe. To do so, you generally need not to use (hidden) state machines and favour thread-local storage. OOP code tends not to be great for that since a primary goal of OOP code is to abstract a state machine (through encapsulation).

Comment: Thank you Jerome for the concise and comprehensive answer, you mentioned that OOP is not greater for a thread-safe code, are there any alternatives to OOP approach for big projects such as this one?

Comment: Functional programming tends to be an interesting approach when dealing with parallel code because states are made visible (and side effects too in pure functional languages). OOP can be Ok in some case. For example, using OOP for containers/data-structure like C++ did is fine as long as each methods are explicitly described are thread-safe of not (and even what kind of thread-safe implementation if possible for sake of performance). OOP is a mess when many objects interact together because no-one can easily tell if a method is thread-safe (likely implementation-dependent).

Comment: Note that data-oriented design is also an interesting approach to both increase performance and help to (efficiently) deal with parallelism in software applications. Still, this approach is not sufficient to design big applications. A good practice is to try to design your application so to split numerically computationally intensive parts and the rest of the code (eg. the parts deciding which algorithms to use, interaction with other libraries, data gathering, etc.). Optimising/Parallelising codes mixing both is just insane (and OOP tends to favour that though this is not required).

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that a `Material` object acts on a `GaussPoint` and without further context there is no way to see if two materials don't act on the same Gauss point. Hence you have a race condition. For a parallelizable code you need to turn this code sideways and consider all Gauss points and ask them for their interaction with the materials.

In my own way of phrasing this, you are using a "push" model, where one object pushes state onto several objects of some other class. For a thread-safe formulation you need to transpose this and use a "pull" model where the other class objects gather all the actions on themselves. Why do I say "transpose"? Well, think of it as a very abstract description of a matrix-vector multiplication. In the "pull" model each output point is an inner product (of a matrix row) with the whole source vector. In the "push" model each input point adds (a scaling of a matrix column) to the whole output. So the one is the transpose product formulation of the other.

And there's a bit of parallelism philosophy for you.

Oh, and as to your direct question: OpenMP lets you shoot yourself in the foot. It will not *detect* conflicts. You have to *avoid* them yourself.

Comment: Thank you Victor, for the answer, I can't say I understand the matrix calculation analogy, but I think I somehow understand what you are saying. Do you have any external link or references in relation to the pull model?

Comment: I should write it up in long form some time.